# Read directory on the server through HTML or Javascript (no AJAX)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to read a directory on a server (without PHP)
The directory names are unknown and I have to link to them.
Is this even possible?

The folder structure could be one like this:

```
 Directory1
    │
    ├── Directory2
    │   ├── index.html (needs to be able to link to directory3)
    ├── Directory3
    │   ├── index.html (needs to be able to link to directory2)
```

Comment: No, you'll need some software running on the server. It doesn't have to be PHP, but *something* needs to respond to the HTTP requests from the client.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation! @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

To find out information about the filesystem of the server, you need to have software running on the server. You can't do it from inside the browser.

That software could be the directory listing feature, common to many HTTP servers, that runs when you request a URL that resolves to a directory on the file system with no Index file.

It could be a custom program written in PHP (or Perl, or Java, or Brainfuck, or whatever).

If you want to get that information to JavaScript running in the browser then you need to transmit it over HTTP. That means Ajax (unless you embed all that data into the HTML document the JS runs inside).

Comment: Yes the problem is, it is a tool to generate HTML files that a user can then upload to some site, so I can't code accept for Javascript.
Well then the user will just have to declare the names of the other directories before generation, thanks for your quick response!